# C function does not show anything

Tags: c

I'm new to c and I'm trying to make a function to return the max between two numbers, and I don't know why it does not work, it does not show anything

```
int max(int num1, int num2) {

   int result;

   if (num1 > num2)
      result = num1;
   else
      result = num2;
 
   return result; 
}


int main()
{
   int result = max(1,2);

   printf("%c", result);

}
```

Comment: Typo in printf: %d for int, not %c.

Comment: The `%c` format specifier is trying to interpret `result` as a character code.  Character code 2 is a non-printing character, which is why you aren't seeing anything.  To interpret it as an integer, use `%d`.  This is essentially a typo.

Answer (score 4):

Small error very last line:

Use "%d" instead of "%c" as your output is an integer and not a character.

```
printf("%d", result);
```

Tip, you may add "\n" at the end which will create a new line on the terminal.

```
printf("max is %d\n", result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using %c in your print. %c is used for print char data type (character). %f for float data type. %i or %d is used for int data type (integer).
Secondly, you are missing return 0; in the end of your function.

Correct code

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max(int num1, int num2) {
  int result;
  if (num1 > num2)
    result = num1;
  else
    result = num2;
  return result;
}
int main() {
  int result = max(1, 2);

  printf("%d", result);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have made a mistake in the print statement. To print an Integer you need to type "%d" instead of %c. This should fix it.

%c prints a Character;
%d prints an Integer

You can refer to this page https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm